# How do I switch Front View Controller using PKRevealController?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I am working with PKRevealController in a new app project, you can get it here:  https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController

The issue I am having is changing the view properly that displays in the Front View Controller.

For example, I swipe the front view to the left or right and have a list of options, one could be Settings for example.  If I tap that I would like the Front View Controller to slide back in place and display the view for the Settings View Controller.

I can get a new view to show up, but it removes the Navigation Controller and messes up the size of the view.

Has anyone successfully figured out how to do this with PKRevealController?

Any tips or advice is much appreciated!

Comment: the answer of @Livio is correct, you should mark as answered.

Comment: have you got solve your problem with this answer?i am having same issues

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView == leftMenu) {
        // Load new front view
        UIViewController *myNewUIViewController = [[MyNewUIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyNewUIViewController" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *myNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myNewUIViewController];
        [self.revealController setFrontViewController:myNavController];
        // Putting back the front view on focus
        [self.revealController showViewController:self.revealController.frontViewController];
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be wasting a lot of memory?  What happens to the navController that was being displayed? 

 Thinking an alternative would be to store an array of view controllers in the sidebar view controller, as they are created. This is similar to the tab bar view controller.

If you have a lot of rows in the sidebar this might not be the best approach, but I don't thinks the above one would work well for that either.